# AudioContext или Audio и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио

Задача: проиграть друг за другом несколько аудиофайлов.
Было несколько попыток сделать это через Audio и через сбор сэмплов в AudioContext, однако моих знаний на это не хватило. ._.

Естественно, что при вызове audio.play() несколько раз подряд происходит одновременное воспроизведение этих файлов и на этом всё.

Подскажите, что можно сделать или где про это почитать?

Comment: Вам нужно по очереди проигрывать все аудиозаписи?

Comment: @Yuri, да, можно и так сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы перелистывать аудиозаписи, запишите все аудио в массив и листайте с помощью `onended`:

```js
var songs = [
  'http://zf.fm/download/4824354',
  'http://zf.fm/download/3860794',
  'http://zf.fm/download/2962900'
];

window.onload = function() {
  var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
  audio.song = 0;
  audio.src = songs[audio.song];
  
  audio.onended = function(e) {
    if(this.song == songs.length - 1){
      this.song = 0;
    }else{
      this.song++;
    };
    this.src = songs[this.song];
    this.play();
  };
};
```

```html
<audio controls="">
```

Comment: Огромная огромная благодарность! :)

Comment: @NetScum, и для общего развития: это можно сделать не добавляя в html audio элемента

Comment: Это я в курсе (var sound = new Audio('src/snd/3.1.wav') например, да?). Я, собственно, так и делаю. У меня отдельные кнопки для воспроизведения звуков стоят. Проблема была именно в том, что я не понимал как организовать вывод звуков друг за другом (не всегда, но иногда такое требуется). С JS вплотную совсем недавно начал работать и многое ещё непонятно. Ещё раз спасибо. :3

Comment: @NetScum, можно в принципе так, или через `document.creatElement('audio')`

Comment: На самой странице, я так полагаю, при этом, ничего не появится (в html тегах, тобишь). Я правильно думаю?

Comment: @NetScum, да. При этом DOM Audio будет в JS хранится